# Is $-\frac{1}{3}\ln|\cos(3x)|$ the same as $\frac{1}{3}\ln|\sec(3x)|$?

Tags: calculus

> Are these equivalent?
>   $$-\frac{1}{3}\ln|\cos(3x)| \;\;\text{and}\;\;\;  \frac{1}{3}\ln|\sec(3x)|$$

If so, how can I convert one to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
-\dfrac{1}{3} \ln|\cos(3x)|= \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot -1\ln|\cos(3x)|= \dfrac{1}{3} \ln|(\cos(3x)^{-1}|= \dfrac{1}{3} \ln\left|\dfrac{1}{\cos(3x)}\right|= \dfrac{1}{3} \ln|\sec(3x)|
$$

Comment: Thanks.  Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For every non zero $x\in\Bbb R$

$$\ln\left|\frac1x\right|=\ln\frac1{|x|}=-\ln|x|$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\ln(1)-\ln(x)=-\ln(x)$$ since $$\ln(1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall $-\ln \vert x\vert= \ln \big\vert\frac{1}{x}\big\vert$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}; x \neq 0$.
$$-\frac{1}{3}\ln\vert \cos(3x)\vert = \frac{1}{3}\ln \vert \sec(3x)\vert$$
$$-\ln\vert \cos(3x)\vert = \ln \vert \sec(3x)\vert$$
$$\ln\biggr\vert \frac{1}{\cos(3x)}\biggr\vert = \frac{1}{3}\ln \vert \sec(3x)\vert \implies \ln\vert \sec(3x)\vert = \ln \vert \sec(3x)\vert$$